# Read JSON String Shown In URL Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to create a simple web app that gets the latitude and longitude stored in a JSON string and uses them to place markers on a google map. Currently, I have a program on a server which retrieves a JSON string with data when a URL is entered into a web browser. The JSON string produced is as follows:-

```
{"employees":[{"email":"bones93@hotmail.co.uk","lat":"53","lon":"-3","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"},{"email":"unknown","lat":"0","lon":"0","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"},{"email":"unknown","lat":"0","lon":"0","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"}]}
```

What method could i use in JavaScript that would allow me to get the JSON string that is produced?

P.S I know I will need to parse the text afterwards to make a JSON Object, this is something that can be done afterwards.

Comment: Is this an AJAX call to the server or something else? What framework is being used server side to process the data and create the JSON object? ASP.net, node.js etc..?

Comment: Basically the server is called using a URL. Inside the URL is an Info parameter. If the value of this parameter is "ALL", the program knows it has to create the JSON string based on every employee. This is when the JSON String previously stated is produced.

Comment: What i need is a method of retrieving the string that is produced. Once this is done, i can simply parse it into a JSON object.

Comment: I guess instead of "read JSON string shown in URL", you mean "get JSON string from URL"? Put that way, the answer becomes sort of self-obvious--you get the string by sending a request to that URL.

Comment: Tryed that and didn't work. Might be a problem with my code. Currently using XmlHttpRequest("GET",url,true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
var x = JSON.parse('{"employees":[{"email":"bones93@hotmail.co.uk","lat":"53","lon":"-3","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"},{"email":"unknown","lat":"0","lon":"0","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"},{"email":"unknown","lat":"0","lon":"0","alt":"0","date":"unknown","time":"unknown"}]}');
```

and then access it with:

```
x["employees"][0]["lat"];
```

Comment: This method would definatly work if the JSON string was hard coded into the Javascript. What I am looking for is basically a way of reading the string that is produced then parsing it into a JSON object.

Comment: You could just use a variable to store the data that you are fetching from the url, and then pass that variable into the JSON.parse whenever you need it parsed.

Comment: The problem isn't with how to use the data being fetched, it is that no data is being fetched. How can i get the string produced on server so that i can parse it in the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Jquery library's get method to request the data from the server. Here is a link to a simple W3 tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Your code will look something like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.get("/your/server/url",function(data){
    var result = JSON.parse(data);
    // Process result.employees
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for normal strings:

```
JSON.parse(str)
```

or if you're using AJAX to get that Json you can use as following:

```
$.get(..,'json')
```

**OR**

```
$.post(..,'json')
```